# Ember: make data use another adapter

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, adapter

guys. I'm creating an app using Ember. The problem is, when im Getting/Posting data to backend, all data is packed into one Json like this:

```
data: {
 users:{
  ...
 },
 address:{
  ...
 }
```

But when i want to update users or addresses they need to be PUT to different endpoints.

My question is, is it possible, to make some portion of data use another adapter?

Comment: you can write your own adapter; have you checked out the [guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/models/customizing-adapters/) as a starting point?

Comment: I know i can.. And i did :). The problem is, how can i tell ember, i want that part of data to be sent via this adapter, and that via another.

Comment: i guess i am missing  sth. why do you need a separate adapter? why is the one single adapter not enough for you? you can always delegate the task to your own classes from that single adapter by checking some conditions.

Comment: Hmm so.. e.g. if(users){ return  path1 } else { return path2 }. I can write contiions in adapters then?

Comment: yes; that is what I am proposing. I have never used `ember-data` myself; so I cannot directly tell you what to do; but someone with some experience should tell I guess. I can also check out when I have some time; but this should be doable as you have indicated.

Comment: Alright, i'll give it a try. Thank you :)